# How do I ensure children of a subprocess don't get SIGINT in Python (on Linux)?

Tags: python, unix, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I'm trying to use a custom job pool (using `multiprocessing.Process`), and it works nicely, except SIGINT gets passed on from the parent process all the way to the children of the pool workers, Chrome instances in this case. I used `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)` in the pool workers, which seems to keep them from getting (or at least responding to) the SIGINT, but I'm using third-party code (Selenium) which creates subprocesses that get the SIGINT and stop because of it. I want only the parent process to receive and handle the SIGINT. How do I do this?

My inclination would be to give the pool workers `/dev/null` as STDIN, so it would give that to its children rather than the terminal, which, if I understand correctly, will keep it from receiving SIGINT from Ctrl+C. However, it seems that `multiprocessing.Process` already does that, though presumably too late (after the process is created; using a double-fork should get past this). Is there a good way to do that (or anything else that blocks SIGINT) through `multiprocessing`, or do I need a different solution to work around that? Maybe there's an easy way to use `multiprocessing.Queue` with `Popen()`, so I can use that instead?

To be clear, I still need to be able to log to the console (indirectly through the parent process is fine, maybe better even).

Comment: You need to put the children in a different process group. See https://www.hasenkopf2000.net/wiki/page/python-and-process-groups/